# Why is it forbidden to use in this inductive step?

Tags: proof-writing, induction

I want to prove $$1+2+~...~+n ~~=~~ \frac{n \cdot (n+1)}{2}$$

and (even though I am absolutely aware of and agree, that there are nicer and more readable ways to write this), I think

$$
\begin{align}
&& 1+2+~...~+k+(k+1) &&=~~~~~~~~ \frac{(k+1) \cdot (k+2)}{2} \\
\\
&\Leftrightarrow \text{(I.H.)} ~~~~~~~~~ & \frac{k \cdot (k+1)}{2} +(k+1) &&=~~~~~~~~ \frac{(k+1) \cdot (k+2)}{2} \\
\\
&\overset{}{\Leftrightarrow} ~~~~~~~~~ & \frac{(k+1) \cdot (k+2)}{2} &&=~~~~~~~~ \frac{(k+1) \cdot (k+2)}{2}
\end{align}\
$$

should be a valid inductive step.

Why is this wrong according to [this document from Carnegie Mellon University](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~15251/notes/induction-pitfalls.pdf)? (See "2 Common Errors and Pitfalls", "2. Proof going the wrong way")

Comment: The error is that in the first line you have already claimed the truth of the proposition you wish to prove by putting an equal sign between the left and right-hand sides.

Comment: I see your point. Sometimes we all use the statement that we want to proof as a part of the proof and it is not correct.

Comment: If you write it down this way, it always helps to put a question mark or some note above the first equation sign, to tell the reader that this is not what you assume but rather the thing you want to show.

Comment: @ekkilop Sorry, please help me understand why this wouldn't be allowed

Comment: @mlk You're right. And I would definitely try to not write a prove in the way as seen above. However, I think this is more a question of bad form and style and not mathematical validity.

Comment: Practice writing proofs in complete, grammatical sentences, preferably short ones, with no abbreviated phrases,  and do not omit any punctuation.  What is "$A\iff (I.H.) B$"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proof is correct once you use $\iff$.

However, in the document you are referring to, it is understood that the implied operation is $\implies$, which is a one-way street. $S_{k+1}$ is assumed in an attempt to prove $S_{k+1}$.

Comment: But in fact all the proof uses is the $\Leftarrow$ direction, and it would be a lot more readable if it were written with that symbol. Better still, use words: "we want to prove ... for which it suffices to show ..." etc.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen yes, using $\impliedby$ is also correct. What the document wants to point out is that using $\implies$ is not correct.

Comment: Also, typically if we see statements going from top to bottom, we would assume that the operator is $\implies$.

Comment: @KennyLau Oh, okay. I am used to assume $\Leftrightarrow$ for omitted logical connectives. I still think, their example in the document is not very good - but at least it makes sense now. Thanks :-)

Comment: @Steph-P Sometimes it is a lot harder to prove that the desired conclusion is true if _and only if_ the given hypothesis is true than to just prove that if the hypothesis is true, then so is the conclusion. So we get out of the habit of connecting all our statements with $\iff$ unless there is a good reason to use $\iff.$